# Ndef Record Creation in NFC Data exchange Format

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

we want to write the following data into NFC:(In two separate lines)

```
Id:A112
Result:Pass
```

and got stuck with `NdefRecord` creation of MIME type text/plain. Actually found two ways of doing so:

- one with constuctor

  ```
  public NdefRecord (short tnf, byte[] type, byte[] id, byte[] payload)
  ```
- other one by using the Static method

  ```
  public static NdefRecord createMime (String mimeType, byte[] mimeData)
  ```

Using the static `createMime` method, we can create the record as:

```
byte[] stringBytes = "Id:A112Result:Pass".getBytes();
NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", stringBytes);
```

How to achieve the same with constructor `NdefRecord` and what's the difference between the above two ways? Also how do we write the above data (Id:A112Result:Pass) into NFC in two lines into a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
public static NdefRecord createMime (String mimeType, byte[] mimeData)
```

using the `NdefRecord`constructor directly is something like this:

```
public NdefRecord myCreateMime (String mimeType, byte[] mimeData) {
    return new NdefRecord(
            NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,
            mimeType.getBytes("US-ASCII"),
            null,
            mimeData)
}
```

In general I would avoid using the text/plain MIME type. This MIME type does not give the payload data any meaning other than it is human-readable text. If you want to convey a specific meaning use an appropriate MIME type that reflects the contents of your payload data or better use a custom NFC Forum external type.

Also note that the MIME type text/plain uses US-ASCII character encoding by default. However, using `"Id:A112Result:Pass".getBytes()` will give you UTF-8 encoding on Android. So you should explicitly specify the character encoding when converting a string to bytes:

```
byte[] stringBytes = "Id:A112Result:Pass".getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Last, if you want to insert a line break anywhere in a text, you would use the new-line escape character `\n` or a combination of carriage return + line feed `\r\n` (depending on your target system's needs).

Comment: @Roland: Thx Roland. Your Post acted as an effective initiative for my research on NFC.